# Разбить строку на отдельные функциональные части

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Задача: разделить строку на части по разделителю ";"
Функция имеет вид Sum(expr) или Sum(expr;condition). Вложенность теоретически бесконечна

Входные данные: Sum(a;b)
Выходные данные
expr = a
condition = b

Входные данные: Sum(a)
Выходные данные
expr = a
condition = null

Входные данные: Sum(Sum(a;c);b)
Выходные данные
expr = Sum(a;c)
condition = b

Входные данные: Sum(Sum(a);Sum(b;d))
Выходные данные
expr = Sum(a)
condition = Sum(b;d)

Подскажите, как лучше обрабатывать такие ситуации. Пробовал через поиск IndexOf(";"), некорректно работает в случае вложенности

Comment: `разделить строку на части по разделителю` - это зовется `Split()`.

Comment: В таком случае, будет разделено по всем вхождениям, насколько я знаю. Мне нужно именно на 2 части разбить, не учитывая разделители во вложенных функциях

Comment: Вы просите разделитель, я вам сказал, что это такое. По поводу количества - ну ведь есть уйма [перегрузок](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) у этого метода, одна из которых [.Split(separator, count)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_).

Comment: Спасибо, я знаю что такое разделитель) Split не подходит для данной задачи, даже с учетом всех перегрузок. В данном случае, если например вызвать метод "Sum(a;c);b".Split(2), то вернется ["Sum(a", "c);b"], что неверно в моем случае

Comment: Возможно, `@"Sum\((\w*(?:\([^()]*\))?)(?:;(\w*(?:\([^()]*\))?)?)\)"` ([пример](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Sum%5c%28%28%5cw*%28%3f%3a%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%5c%29%29%3f%29%28%3f%3a%3b%28%5cw*%28%3f%3a%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%5c%29%29%3f%29%3f%29%5c%29&i=Sum%28a%3bb%29%0d%0aSum%28a%29%0d%0aSum%28Sum%28a%3bc%29%3bb%29%0d%0aSum%28Sum%28a%29%3bSum%28b%3bd%29%29))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Он не работает при Sum(a)

Comment: Точно, сам запутался. Вот, вроде, [работает](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Sum%5c%28%0d%0a++%28%0d%0a+++%5cw*%28%3f%3a%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%5c%29%29%3f%0d%0a++%29%0d%0a++%28%3f%3a%0d%0a++++%3b%0d%0a++++%28%5cw*%28%3f%3a%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%5c%29%29%3f%29%0d%0a++%29%3f%0d%0a%5c%29&i=Sum%28a%3bb%29%0d%0aSum%28a%29%0d%0aSum%28Sum%28a%3bc%29%3bb%29%0d%0aSum%28Sum%28a%29%3bSum%28b%3bd%29%29&o=x): `Sum\((\w*(?:\([^()]*\))?)(?:;(\w*(?:\([^()]*\))?))?\)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо) но тут вложенность ограничена, насколько я понял. На таком выражении Sum(Sum(Sum(a;b);Sum(c;d));Sum(b;d)) уже не работает( У меня есть идея попробовать ввести стек скобок для разбора. Возможно это поможет в случае с неограниченной вложенностью

Comment: Ок, это не проблема, я напишу ответ позже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришел к такому решению. Комментарии приветствуются) На вход в функцию передается только внутренняя часть формулы

```
private static List<string> SplitByDelimeter(string expression)
    {
        var res = new List<string>();
        Stack<char> brackets = new Stack<char>();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var ch in expression)
        {
            if (ch == '(')
                brackets.Push(ch);
            if (ch == ')')
                brackets.Pop();

            if (ch == ';' && brackets.Count == 0)
            {
                res.Add(builder.ToString());
                builder = new StringBuilder();
                continue;
            }

            builder.Append(ch);
        }

        if (builder.Length > 0)
            res.Add(builder.ToString());

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Это весьма неплохое решение, мне например нравится отказ от решения решить задачу регулярками и нравится использование стека в нужном месте для понимания уровня вложенности -- это уместное использование подходящих структур данных, как и StringBuilder. Вероятно, идеальное решение было бы описать грамматику языка и честно писать парсер -- но если вам зачем-то нужно такое узкое и конкретное решение, то свою задачу оно должно выполнять нормально (не запускал, просто в голове прокрутил алгоритм).

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать

```cs
var pattern = @"(?x)Sum\(      # текст Sum(
  (                            # Начало первой подмаски
   \w*(?:\((?>[^()]+|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*(?(c)(?!))\))? # 1 слово и необязательная подстрока между ( и )
  )                            # Конец первой подмаски
  (?:                          # Начало незахватывающей подмаски
    ;                          # точка с запятой
    (\w*(?:\((?>[^()]+|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*(?(c)(?!))\))?) # см. выше
  )?                           # Конец незахватывающей подмаски, 1 и 0 раз
\)                             # Символ ) ";
```

См. [пример использования регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Sum%5C%28%0D%0A%20%20%28%0D%0A%20%20%20%5Cw*%28%3F%3A%5C%28%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Cc%3E%29%5C%28%7C%28%3F%3C-c%3E%29%5C%29%29*%28%3F%28c%29%28%3F!%29%29%5C%29%29%3F%0D%0A%20%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%28%3F%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%28%5Cw*%28%3F%3A%5C%28%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%3Cc%3E%29%5C%28%7C%28%3F%3C-c%3E%29%5C%29%29*%28%3F%28c%29%28%3F!%29%29%5C%29%29%3F%29%0D%0A%20%20%29%3F%0D%0A%5C%29&i=Sum%28a%3Bb%29%0D%0ASum%28a%29%0D%0ASum%28Sum%28a%3Bc%29%3Bb%29%0D%0ASum%28Sum%28a%29%3BSum%28b%3Bd%29%29%0D%0ASum%28Sum%28Sum%28a%3Bb%29%3BSum%28c%3Bd%29%29%3BSum%28b%3Bd%29%29&o=x)

Результаты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]